# Multple connection simulation to a MQTT Server using same machine

Tags: networking, server, network-programming, mqtt, admin

I have a custom designed Embedded MQTT Server that is running on port 1883. I wanted to do its load testing. I wanted to make at least 200 simultaneous connection to this MQTT Server. As per normal networking concepts, if I make a connection to the MQTT Server from my laptop using 1883 port, I cannot make another connection using same port. I have 5 laptops but using these 5 laptops I can only create 5 connection, How can I solve this issue of making multiple connection to the same MQTT Server using single laptop?

Answer (score 2):

You are connecting **TO** port 1883, not **FROM** port 1883.  Whatever method you use to create a connection, it will use an "Ephemeral" port (IE> ports 1025 to 65535.) You just have to make sure that you don't reuse the same client ID...and if you don't specify the client ID, most MQTT modules/libraries will auto-generate a unique Client ID for you.

Comment: Google MQTT simulator to do this in minutes. We do tens of thousands, if not hundreds of thousands of connections.